# Given the one-form $a$, find $α_p(v_p)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given the one-form $a= xy^2 dx − \sqrt{ yz}dy + (x + z)^{2/3} dz$, and $p=(2,-1,3)$ find $α_p(v_p)$
where $(i)v_p=(2,-2,1)$, $(ii)v_p=2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} − 3\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + 4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

---

$(i),     a_p(v_p)=( 2(-1)^2 dx −  (-1)1dy + (2 + 3)^{2/3} dz)(2,-2,1)=4dx-2dy+5^{2/3}dz$

$(ii),  a_p(v_p)=( 2(-1)^2 dx −  (-1)1dy + (2 + 3)^{2/3} dz)(2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} − 3\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + 4\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=4-3+4\cdot 5^{2/3}$

Am I doing this correct ?

Comment: $\sqrt{yz}$ makes no sense when $y=-1$, $z=3$.

Comment: No. When you evaluate a $1$-form at $p$ on a tangent vector at $p$, the answer is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

We have the one form
$$\Omega^1(\mathbb R^3)\ni\alpha(x,y,z)=xy^2dx-\sqrt{yz} dy+(x+z)^{2/3}dz$$
and the tangent vector of $T_p\mathbb R^3$ is
$$v_p=2\partial_x\vert_p-2\partial_y\vert_p+\partial_z\vert_p$$
Remember that if we call $x^1,x^2,x^3$ the coordinates of the real space, we have $dx^j(\partial_{x^i})=\begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\ne j \end{cases},\text{ for }i,j=1,2,3$.
$$\alpha(v_p)=(xy^2dx-\sqrt{yz}dy+(x+z)^{2/3}dz)(v_p)=\\xy^2dx(v_p)-\sqrt{yz}dy(v_p)+(x+z)^{2/3}dz(v_p)=\\xy^2dx(2\partial_x\vert_p-2\partial_y\vert_p+\partial_z\vert_p)-\sqrt{yz}dy(2\partial_x\vert_p-2\partial_y\vert_p+\partial_z\vert_p)+(x+z)^{2/3}dz(2\partial_x\vert_p-2\partial_y\vert_p+\partial_z\vert_p)=\\2xy^2-2 \sqrt{yz}+(x+z)^{2/3}$$
and you can now evaluate this in $p$. Are you sure the point is $(2,-1,3)?$

Comment: Maybe was a typo, i didn't notice, doesn't really matter though. I just need to know if the methods are correct.

Comment: Remeber that  a one form is a map $\omega_p:T_pM\to \mathbb R$, so when you evaluate the form on a point $p$ you don't obtain a one form as you wrote.